# What is the difference between :End of file (EOF) ,End of stream ,and string !=NULL in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

what is the difference  between  using 
`StreamReader.EndOfStream`, and  `string != null`  in files handling

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
String line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
}






 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                data = BreakLine(line);
                DataRow dr = _DataTable.NewRow();
                // protect against overflow
                int maxColumns = Math.Min(_DataTable.Columns.Count, data.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = data[i];
                }
                _DataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: What is "EOF constant"?

Comment: Samples of each would make this question more answerable.

Comment: @HSN: could you post a MSDN link to this constant? I have no idea, what are you talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two handle different situations. If you operate on a file, `EOF` will indicate that your file-pointer reached the end of the file, whereas a `Stream` is a continous stream of data (usually uni-directional as opposed to a file where you usually have random access to).

From [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wjk/C++Intro/RobMillerL4.html) it says about files

```
"The easiest way to think about a file is as a linear sequence of characters."
```

and about streams it says

```
"We can think of a stream as a channel or conduit on which data is passed from senders to receivers."
```

Read the article to get an impression. Although it is about `C++`, it reflects the basics very well.